# Can't find cookie in GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension using AngularJS that requires the user to log in for full functionality. Before running the app on the page, I do a `GET` request in order to fetch the current user by their session cookie.

The cookie gets set on my domain, and if the cookie has already been set, I can execute the `GET` request successfully from any arbitrary domain, even though I cannot see the cookie in `document.cookies` from that arbitrary domain. Conversely, if the cookie is expired/invalid or has not been set from my domain, the `GET` request fails -- which is fine.

However, because I'm using a popup window to my domain for validation (from any arbitrary domain that the extension is running on), I need to know when the cookie was set in order to execute my `GET` request (I could, in theory, continuously execute `GET` requests until I get a valid user back, but I don't want to waste bandwidth / cycles). I know the cookie is there, since the `GET` works, but I can't get at it with `document.cookie`. My questions:

*Where is the cookie being sent to my server actually stored, and how can I view it?*

*If there is no way for me to view this cookie, what would be a good alternative way of knowing when to execute the `GET` request that depends on this cookie?*

Comment: If you're using nodejs, why can't you just check against the _session on the server?

Comment: @Phil I can; the server sees my request with the cookie fine, and sends back an appropriate response. However, I don't want to flood the server with requests until I get a proper one back. I want to check for the existence of the cookie before sending this request.

Comment: Could be a long shot but  have you set the withcredentials attribute to true? (assuming its an AJAX request)

`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`

Comment: Not that I'm aware... I'm actually using `$http` method of AngularJS, I'm assuming it's got some sort of a preset value for this @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`chrome.cookies` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) to query/monitor the cookie store.

You can query the current state of the store with `chrome.cookies.get()` and/or subscribe to modifications of the cookie store with `chrome.cookies.onChanged` event.

Don't forget the `"cookies"` permission.